# How to link a data source with dot42?

Tags: c#, android, dot42

I just started using dot42 as I would like to write some simple android apps in c#. When doing a c# project it is really simple to add and link a SQL database to it.

For some reason, it is not as simple with dot42. Am I doing something wrong? There isn't much documentation for it online and a google search did not bring up anything.

Thanks for reading my question.